# Using a button in a list-divider in JQuery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery Mobile. I have a page that looks like the following:

```
<div id="myPage" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My App</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview"> 
            <li data-role="list-divider">
                <div data-type='horizontal'>Hello&nbsp;
                <a href='#' id='moreOptions' data-role='button' data-icon='arrow-d' data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-iconpos='notext'>more</a>
            </div></li>            
        </ul><br /><br />

        My App Content
    </div>
</div>
```

I have some JavaScript that determines whether to display the "moreOptions" button. My problem is, when the "moreOptions" button is shown The height of the list-divider area expands beyond the normal size. Is there a way I can use CSS to keep the list-divider area the standard height? Or, can I somehome scale down the button size?

Thank you!

Comment: can you post what your javascript does to show/hide the `moreOptions` button?

Answer (score 0):

Isolate the CSS class of the list divider (.ui-li-divider, I think) and add the max-height property. It should look like this:

```
.ui-li-divider{
max-height: 20px;
}
```